# Keyboard macro with occur

Tags: window, window-splitting, keyboard-macros, occur

In a keyboard macro, there is an `occur` command. While recording the macro, I switched to the occur window, did some editing, closed occur buffer reverted back to original buffer to continue editing.

When I try executing that keyboard macro, it fails just after opening the occur window.

How do I get the macro to continue executing the commands?